# Any way to print out a type of a variable in a do / where / let block?

Tags: haskell, ghci

Is there any way to print out the inferred type of a nested variable in `ghci`? Consider the code,

```
let f = g where
    g (x :: Int) = x
```

then, it'd be nice to query the type of `g`, e.g. `:t f.g` would print out `Int -> Int`.

Comment: Doesn't `g` have the same type as `f`? `:t f`.

Comment: Incidentally, how did you get ghci to accept a multi-line statement? It never worked for me.

Comment: @snail surround your multi-line statement with `{:` and `:}` on their own lines.

Comment: @pat Awesome, thanks for the trick! I was actually saving it to a file. You have a typo though, it's `:{`.

Comment: oops, and I even went into ghci to check it first...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can coax this information out by giving an appropriately wrong type annotation and checking the error message.

```
*Main> let f = g where g::a; g (x::Int) = x

<interactive>:1:23:
    Couldn't match type `a1' with `Int -> Int'
      `a1' is a rigid type variable bound by...
```

Comment: This is definitely the more convenient solution. When you have just "a", it seems to work pretty well. However, I do happen to have a specific case where I have a variable in a do block, using scoped variables, where the type annotation doesn't seem to reveal anything. (odd, maybe I should file a bug).

Answer (score 10):

ghci debugger can print it for you with a properly placed breakpoint (but you'll need to load your definition within a module):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-} 

f a = g a where
    g (x :: Int) = x
```

Then in ghci:

```
Prelude> :l tmp2.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( tmp2.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> :b 3 9
Breakpoint 0 activated at tmp2.hs:3:7-9
*Main> f undefined
Stopped at tmp2.hs:3:7-9
_result :: Int = _
a :: Int = _
g :: Int -> Int = _
[tmp2.hs:3:7-9] *Main>
```

Comment: I found this easier than the other answer, because sometimes you get different errors by forcing the type, but this way you always find out the type.