# Print function type to console without ghci

Tags: haskell, ghc

Is there a way of printing the function or expression type to the command line in a compiled `Haskell` program, much like how `ghci` has `:t` which prints out the type?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756721/any-way-to-print-out-a-type-of-a-variable-in-a-do-while-let-block

Comment: @Noctua No, that uses the interactive features of ghci again, and won't work via ghc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With a `Typeable` constraint (from `Data.Typeable`), you can use `show . typeOf`.